# CSS - Only wrap text between elements, NOT characters (can't use a space)

Tags: html, css, whitespace, element, line-breaks

Let's say I have a few `<span>` elements like this, with no spaces between the elements:

```
<span>aaaaaaaaaa</span><span>bbbbbbbbbb</span><span>cccccccccc</span>
```

When rendered in a browser, and is being horizontally "squished", I would like the text to wrap ONLY between elements. So, only the first two examples should be allowed:

**1. ✔ No wrapping:**

```
aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc
```

**2. ✔ Element-only wrapping:**

```
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccc
```

**3. ❌ Character wrapping (this must not be allowed):**

```
aaaaaaaa
aabbbbbb
bbbbcccc
cccccc
```

How do I prevent the characters from wrapping in CSS? Normally I'd put a space between the elements to get them to wrap properly, but I can't use spaces in this specific case. I've tried the following, but characters still wrap with this (in Firefox, at least):

```
<style>
.b{
word-break:break-all;
}
.n{
word-break:normal;
}
</style>

<span class="b"><span class="n">aaaaaaaaaa</span><span class="n">bbbbbbbbbb</span><span class="n">cccccccccc</span></span>
```

Comment: Do you have to use spans? Can you not use a block element with floats?

Comment: @DGS potayto potahto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `white-space: nowrap` (which will prevent wrapping within a single `.n` element), combined with `display: inline-block` (which will render the elements as inline block-level elements):

```css
.n {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="b">
  <span class="n">aaaaaaaaaa</span><span class="n">bbbbbbbbbb</span><span class="n">cccccccccc</span>
</span>
```

This will render the elements beside each other if there is room, or wrap them if there isn't enough room, however no wrapping is allowed within a single `.n` element.

On a side note, I suggest using more descriptive class names. This will become a nightmare to maintain very quickly.

Comment: What worked was adding the "display:inline-block" property. The "white-space:nowrap" is unnecessary, since there is no white-space between the elements anyway.

Comment: @user3163495 You mentioned wrapping within the `<span>`, so I assumed you might have some white space in there. However I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use flexbox in this scenario. Here's an example:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<span class="flex">
  <span>aaaaaaaaaa</span>
  <span>bbbbbbbbbb</span>
  <span>cccccccccc</span>
</span>
```

Flexbox is great for organizing elements on the page like this, I highly recommend researching it further.

EDIT: The other answers may be better for your situation. Flexbox is really powerful for organizing lots of content, but it may be over-engineering if you need something simple.